# Browsing to permalink prefix results in 404

Tags: permalinks, 404-error

I have set my blog permalink as follows:

```
/news/%postname%
```

This works. Going to any post, such as `/news/test`, will serve the `single.php` as expected. I can also browse to a category such as `/news/category/uncategorized`, which brings up the `archive.php`. All good.

However, when I browse to `/news` (which I was expecting to also bring up `archive.php`) I get a `404` and I don't understand why? I was at least expecting to be served the `index.php` not a `404`.

Ideally I have the `archive.php` template served by browsing to `/news` but to solve the `404` issue first would be great.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

**PS**: I was hoping to prevent to create a dummy `/news` page.

**PPS**: Yes, I always clear my permalinks by saving them from the Settings panel.

Answer (score 1):

if you're trying to make the news serve as a homepage you should use the Site address (URL) in the WordPress general setting options.

and of course you'll getting an 404 error page since the news/ in your permalink serve as a directory which is refer to your server directory that not connected with the WordPress itself. try to create a news directory in your public_html and add some index page to see what happen.